# Searchable dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a search input box above the dropdown list in my site, mind to tell me how to make a searchable dropdown list ?

```
echo "<td>";
echo "<select name='customer_name' style='width: 300px;'>";
$sql = mysql_query("select * from master_add where tipe = 'customer'");
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo "<option value='$r[desc1]'>$r[desc2]</option>";
} 
echo "</select>";
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Jquery, javascript, ajax will much help for this

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Use templates, kids.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs K Old Guy

Comment: @AdhanTimothyYounes Thx u brother :)

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: @ThomasMoors Wow its really helpful bro :D thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You can try [silviomoreto/bootstrap-select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) to build your searchable dropdown list.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/koft9cpu/)

> See https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:

- PHP -> you submit the researched value and create dynamically your menu with it. It can be great if your dropdown is really big or if you don't print every possible result at beginning.
- JS -> you need to call a function on submit/keyup action of your input. Then, you can rewrite the new menu as you would in php (still js style) or hide/show the elements you desired.

However, your question seems not liked for because of the leak of research: you can't just ask "how can I do that", you need to show use real code so we could help you, not make it for you.

Comment: Actuallly i dont need your code,just tell me the logic.
but thank u for the answer bro :)